# Asp.net Active Directory LDAP: Trying to filter down into a group level

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, active-directory, ldap

I have created a login page in asp.net using c# but I am having difficulty trying to only allow a certain group to have access.  Right now I am accessing everyone but I can't seem to just filter the group that I need so only those person(s) can have access to my application.

Any help would be great so I can just permission this application out to that one group within Active Directory.

Here is my class that I am using to pass the groups:

```
public class LdapAuthentication
{
    private string _path;
    private string _filterAttribute;

    public LdapAuthentication(string path)
    {
        _path = path;
    }

    public bool IsAuthenticated(string domain, string username, string pwd)
    {
      string domainAndUsername = domain + @"\" + username;
      DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry( _path, domainAndUsername, pwd);

      try
      { 
        // Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
        Object obj = entry.NativeObject;
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
        SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
        if(null == result)
        {
          return false;
        }
        // Update the new path to the user in the directory
        _path = result.Path;
        _filterAttribute = (String)result.Properties["cn"][0];
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        throw new Exception("Error authenticating user. " + ex.Message);
      }
      return true;
    }

    public string GetGroups()
    {
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(_path);
        search.Filter = "(cn=" + _filterAttribute + ")";
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
        StringBuilder groupNames = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
            int propertyCount = result.Properties["memberOf"].Count;
            String dn;
            int equalsIndex, commaIndex;

            for (int propertyCounter = 0; propertyCounter < propertyCount;
                 propertyCounter++)
            {
                dn = (String)result.Properties["memberOf"][propertyCounter];

                equalsIndex = dn.IndexOf("=", 1);
                commaIndex = dn.IndexOf(",", 1);
                if (-1 == equalsIndex)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                groupNames.Append(dn.Substring((equalsIndex + 1),
                                  (commaIndex - equalsIndex) - 1));
                groupNames.Append("|");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error obtaining group names. " +
              ex.Message);
        }
        return groupNames.ToString();
    }

    public bool isMember( String groupname )
    {
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(_path);
        search.Filter = "(cn=" + _filterAttribute + ")";
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
        try
        {
            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
            int propertyCount = result.Properties["memberOf"].Count;

            for (int propertyCounter = 0; propertyCounter < propertyCount;
                    propertyCounter++)
            {
                String dn = (String)result.Properties["memberOf"][propertyCounter];
                // The comma in the regex is important to prevent accidental matches
                if ( Regex.IsMatch( dn, @"cn="+groupname+",.*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                    return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            // Some logging here probably
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

It has to be in the Get groups function but I am not sure how to pass the group I am looking for.  If anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Here is my button click event:

```
    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Path to you LDAP directory server.
        // Contact your network administrator to obtain a valid path.
        string adPath = "LDAP://domain.com";
        LdapAuthentication adAuth = new LdapAuthentication(adPath);
        String myGroupName = "Some_Group";

        try
        {
            if (true == adAuth.IsAuthenticated(txtDomainName.Text, txtLoginID.Text, txtPassword.Text))
            {
                if( adAuth.isMember( myGroupName ) )
                  {
                      // User is authenticated and a member of the group. 
                      // Create your auth ticket, cookie, and whatnot
                      // Retrieve the user's groups
                        string groups = adAuth.GetGroups();
                        // Create the authetication ticket
                        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,  // version
                                                          txtLoginID.Text,
                                                          DateTime.Now,
                                                          DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),
                                                          false, groups);
                        // Now encrypt the ticket.
                        string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
                        // Create a cookie and add the encrypted ticket to the 
                        // cookie as data.
                        HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

                        // Add the cookie to the outgoing cookies collection.
                        Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

                        // Redirect the user to the originally requested page
                        //Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(txtLoginID.Text, false));

                        Response.Redirect("LookupEdit.aspx");   
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      lblError.Text = "Authorization failed. You are not a member of the "+myGroupName+" group";
                  }
                }
                else
                {
                  lblError.Text = "Authentication did not succeed. Check user name and password.";
                }
              }
              catch(Exception ex)
              {
                lblError.Text = "Error authenticating. " + ex.Message;
              }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so after your comments, here's what you should do:

Create an `isMember(String)` function in your LdapAuthentication class:

```
public boolean isMember( String groupname )
{
    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(_path);
    search.Filter = "(cn=" + _filterAttribute + ")";
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
    try
    {
        SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
        int propertyCount = result.Properties["memberOf"].Count;

        for (int propertyCounter = 0; propertyCounter < propertyCount;
             propertyCounter++)
        {
            String dn = (String)result.Properties["memberOf"][propertyCounter];
            // The comma in the regex is important to prevent accidental matches
            if ( Regex.IsMatch( dn, @"cn="+groupname+",.*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
              return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { // Some logging here probably
    }
    return false;
}
```

Next, add this as your btnlogin_Click code:

```
<script runat=server>
void btnlogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  String adPath = "LDAP://your.domain.com"; //Enter your domain name here
  LdapAuthentication adAuth = new LdapAuthentication(adPath);
  String myGroupName = "auth-group-name"; //Enter your group's name (cn) here
  try
  {
    if(true == adAuth.IsAuthenticated(txtDomain.Text, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text))
    {
      if( adAuth.isMember( myGroupName ) )
      {
          // User is authenticated and a member of the group. 
          // Create your auth ticket, cookie, and whatnot
      }
      else
      {
          errorLabel.Text = "Authorization failed. You are not a member of the "+myGroupName+" group";
      }
    }
    else
    {
      errorLabel.Text = "Authentication did not succeed. Check user name and password.";
    }
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    errorLabel.Text = "Error authenticating. " + ex.Message;
  }
}
</script>
```

This should do the trick for you. Obviously you should create some code after the `isMember()` check to create a secure cookie that allows other pages to check the authenticated state of the user.

Good luck.

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing this right but in the if statement if you look above I have some updated code.  Is this correct?  It is telling me that I am not a member of the group that I am trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having issues with this. I use pretty much the same class as you do to do the AD authentication. I was using a different way to connect to AD but was having some strange problems. I implemented a Role Provider before I changed to this code and I'm still using that Role provider to deny and grant access. This is how I basically did it. [Follow this link](http://slalomdev.blogspot.com/2008/08/active-directory-role-provider.html) as it will help you set up the roles.

The only thing I changed up was the "GetRolesForUser" with..

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
{
    var allRoles = new List();
    var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username);
    if (user != null)
    {
       var groups = user.GetGroups();
       allRoles.AddRange(groups.Select(x => x.Name));
    }

    return allRoles.ToArray();
}
```

This way, you can deny and grant groups within the web.config.

I do it like this..

```
<location path="TestPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="SoftwareDevelopers" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
 </location>
```

So I'm denying everyone access to the TestPage.aspx besides the AD group SoftwareDevelopers.

I hope this helps. 
EDIT: If you are using the link that is in the comment to do this active directory, one way to get the group is using the authentication ticket that's created when you login.

```
        if (Request.Cookies["ADAuthCookie"] != null)
        {
            HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

            string cookiePath = ticket.CookiePath;
            DateTime expiration = ticket.Expiration;
            bool expired = ticket.Expired;
            bool isPersistent = ticket.IsPersistent;
            DateTime issueDate = ticket.IssueDate;
            string name = ticket.Name;
            string userData = ticket.UserData;
            int version = ticket.Version;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(cookiePath);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(expiration);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(expired);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(isPersistent);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(issueDate);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(name);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(userData);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(version);

            if (userData.Contains("SoftwareDevelopers"))
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "You're a software developer.";
            }

        }
```

You will have to decrypt the ticket to be able to read the information. I have provided how to write it to the console so you could see how it works. If you wanted to, the if statement provided above is one way you can restrict/show parts of a page.

However, I'm finding that the link in this answer on how to set up the ADRoleProvider is probably going to be your best route.

Comment: What if you need to pass it within a login page.  I have a login page that I would need to pass this too so the user can access it.

Comment: I have tried that as well, no luck for me but again, I was using my role provider and that seems to be the best route. If you are using this link.. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316748 ... then it shows the button click you can use... The ADRoleProvider in that link will show you how to use web.config and use simple if statements to check to see if a user is in that group or not.

Comment: Take a look at my edit. See if that makes sense. It should if you are using the link above to verify against the AD.

Comment: @Humpy Please note that the microsoft support article creates a web application with _client-side security_. They suggest keeping the resolved group names in a cookie or a hidden form field, meaning anyone could create fake groupmembership values. Please do not follow its advice!

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if the user is a member of the correct group, right? 
Why not create a function that accepts a group name and returns boolean, like this:

```
public boolean isMember( String username, String groupname )
    {
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(_path);
        search.Filter = "(cn=" + username + ")";
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
        try
        {
            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
            int propertyCount = result.Properties["memberOf"].Count;

            for (int propertyCounter = 0; propertyCounter < propertyCount;
                 propertyCounter++)
            {
                String dn = (String)result.Properties["memberOf"][propertyCounter];
                // The comma in the regex is important to prevent accidental matches
                if ( Regex.IsMatch( dn, @"cn="+groupname+",.*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                  return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { // Some logging here probably
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The best way is to let LDAP do the membership iteration, by specifying the groupname in your search. However that requires the `groupname` to be the complete group *DN* (e.g. `cn=mygroup,ou=groups,dc=xxx,dc=xxx`) so this might not be feasible for you:

```
public boolean isMember( String username, String groupdn )
    {
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(_path);
        // Escaping the input strings is advisable from a security standpoint!
        search.Filter = "(&(cn=" + username + ")(memberOf=" + groupdn + "))";
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
        try
        {
            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
            // The LDAP server has done the matching for us
            if ( result != null )
               return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { // Some logging here probably
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Good luck!

Comment: Ok, so then how would I call the isMember function in my btnlogin_Click code.  That's where I am having the issue.  I need it to validate that these persons are a part of the group I am trying to only be able to login to this application.  I am so stuck on this it's crazy.